# Extend this procedure to load various data tables as needed

Tags: .net, vb.net, dry

I have added the following class to load a specific DataTable from the database. The DataTable is only loaded when first needed, but then remains available for the rest of the time the program is open. It's useful for lookup tables that rarely change, but I don't necessarily need every time the program is used.

It works well, but I will need several similar tables. What I'd like is to make this class more generic/reuseable so that I don't just have dozens of these copy/pasted with nothing but the names of the Properties changed. Any suggestions?

```
Public Class StatesService
    Private Shared _statesDataTable As DataTable
    Private Shared _initLock As Object = New Object()

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property StatesDataTable() As DataTable
        Get
            If (_statesDataTable Is Nothing) Then InitializeData()
            Return _statesDataTable
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Shared Sub InitializeData()
        SyncLock _initLock
            If (_statesDataTable Is Nothing) Then
                _statesDataTable = DB.GetStatesFromDatabase()
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is that what a DataSet is for?

Comment: @Plutonix A DataSet is for grouping and relating multiple DataTables, right? My DataTables aren't necessarily related, and I don't need to load all of them at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. The first time a table is needed, it is loaded from the database. It is then available for any subsequent use.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class CommonData
    Private Shared _initLock As Object = New Object()
    Private Shared _tableDictionary As Dictionary(Of Tables, DataTable)

    Public Shared Function GetTable(table As Tables) As DataTable
        If _tableDictionary Is Nothing Then
            _tableDictionary = New Dictionary(Of Tables, DataTable)
        End If

        If Not _tableDictionary.ContainsKey(table) OrElse _tableDictionary(table) Is Nothing Then
            InitializeData(table)
        End If

        Return _tableDictionary(table)
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub InitializeData(table As Tables)
        SyncLock _initLock

            Dim dt As DataTable = DB.GetDataFor(table)
            dt.TableName = table.ToString

            If _tableDictionary.ContainsKey(table) Then
                _tableDictionary.Remove(table)
            End If

            _tableDictionary.Add(table, dt)

        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Public Enum Tables
        States
        TimeZones
        Options
    End Enum

End Class
```

A table can be used by calling the `GetTable` function:

```
dgvStates.DataSource = CommonData.GetTable(CommonData.Tables.States)
```

I used an Enum to avoid spelling errors or calling undefined tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object instances from a non-shared class rather than having multiple shared classes. But before you need to be able to get instance of a `DataTable` from your `DB` class by tableName or some other specific property which can separate different tables:

```
Public Class DbLockService

    Private _dt As DataTable
    Private _initLock As Object = New Object()
    Public TableName As String

    Sub New(ByVal tableName As String)
        Me.TableName = tableName
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Table As DataTable
        Get
            If _dt Is Nothing Then
                Me.InitializeData()
            End If
            Return _dt
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub InitializeData()
        SyncLock _initLock
            _dt = db.GetTableByItsName(Me.TableName)
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then define and call tables this way:

```
    Dim StatesTable As New DbLockService("StatesTable")
    dgv.DataSource = StatesTable.Table
```

Comment: Looks good to me. I'll give it a try next week and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like any form that needs to access one of these tables has to create a new instance of DbLockService, and the table field will be reloaded from the database for each instance. This is what I was trying to avoid. But your answer gave me the inspiration I needed. I posted my final version separately.

Comment: Keeping instances to avoid creating new instances are very easy. You could keep your different tables in a module or a class's shared variable and just initializing them at constructor. For sharing tables dictionary rather than on table per lock your code is just searching in a dictionary and it would be doing same thing as my code but somehow slower logically (Because of searching in dictionary rather than keeping just it's own object instance).

Comment: And you shared your locking `_initLock` variable for different tables which I think it will through null exception at the case you call two `GetTable()` functions in async way but I'm not sure about this without test. Otherwise I should change my `Private _initLock As Object = New Object()` code to `Private Shared _initLock As Object = New Object()` to work correct as you done.